# using ifPresent with orElseThrow

Tags: java, option-type

So I must be missing something, I'm looking to execute a statement block if an Optional is present otherwise throw an exception.

```
Optional<X> oX;

oX.ifPresent(x -> System.out.println("hellow world") )
.orElseThrow(new RuntimeException("x is null");
```

if `oX` is not null then print hellow world.
if `oX` is `null` then throw the runtime exception.

Comment: What's the problem? Is this all the code? You never Initialize `oX`. Working with optionals doesn't mean that the objects can be null. Are you getting a NPE?

Comment: Its intended as pseudo code.
Assume that oX has been passed in and can be either null or not null.

My understanding is that Optionals can be null e.g. Optional.ofNullable.  The point here is to execute code if its not null otherwise throw a custom exception if it is.

Comment: Why would you need `ifPresent`? `orElseThrow` returns your `X`, you can just consume that directly.

Comment: @daniu I've just been playing with that concept and can't see how it works. Can you provide a rewrite of the above.

Comment: OK, I worked it out.

   Optional<String> oX = Optional.of("Hellow Word");
   String x = oX.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("x is null"));
   System.out.println(x);

Comment: A null Optional, like any other null Object, will throw NPE when you execute any method on it. The Object inside an Optional is optionally present or null. When you create an Optional using Optional.ofNullable(object) then the "object" can be null.

Comment: Usage: The value in the `Optional` is said to be *present* or *absent*. It is never said to be null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just consume your element directly.

```
X x = oX.orElseThrow(new RuntimeException("x is null");
System.out.println(x);
```

Or

```
System.out.println(oX.orElseThrow(new RuntimeException("x is null"));
```

Comment: How do I accept your answer? I've just increased your vote count but I don't think that marks it as the selected answer.

Comment: @BrettSutton Click that faint grey tick thing to the left of the answer, which will make it turn green.

Comment: Looks like there is a minimum interval must pass before you can mark a question answered as the tick wasn't originally appearing.

Answer (score 15):

With Java-8, what you can do is use `if...else` as:

```
if(oX.ifPresent()) {
    System.out.println("hello world");  // ofcourse get the value and use it as well
} else { 
   throw new RuntimeException("x is null");
}
```

With Java-9 and above, you can use `ifPresentOrElse`

```
optional.ifPresentOrElse(s -> System.out.println("hello world"), 
        () -> {throw new RuntimeException("x is null");});
```

Comment: Worth noting that the Java-9 method can only throw RuntimeExceptions, checked Exceptions are not allowed. Whereas the `if...else` can throw both

Answer (score 3):

The **accepted answer** has an issue when the throwable is not implemented with the Supplier interface.
To Avoid That, You can use the lambda expression as below.

```
X x = oX.orElseThrow(()-> new CustomException("x is null");
System.out.println(x);
```